# How to return a string in reverse separated by a special character in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string like this `"Planck, Albert, Bohr"`

I want the output as `"Bohr Albert Planck"`

I want this done using SQL server. I saw many string split functions all return the data as a table and in the forward order. These don't server my purpose.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This what you want:

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dest VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @lenght INT 

SET @source = 'Planck, Albert, Bohr'
SET @dest = ''

WHILE LEN(@source) > 0
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX(' ', @source) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @dest = SUBSTRING(@source,0,CHARINDEX(' ', @source)) + ' ' + @dest
        SET @source = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@source,CHARINDEX(' ', 
                      @source)+1,LEN(@source))))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @dest = @source + ' ' + @dest
        SET @source = ''
    END
END

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@dest,Char(44),''),Char(13), '')
```

`Char(44)` is the ASCII value for `,` so at last I am just replacing that character.

This will print `Bohr Albert Planck`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a split string function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/314917/569436) you can do something like this.

```
declare @S varchar(20) = 'Planck, Albert, Bohr'

select
(
  select ltrim(s)+' '
  from dbo.Split(',', @S)
  order by pn desc
  for xml path(''), type
).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b169a/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @inStr varchar(1000)='Planck, Albert, Bohr'
;WITH CTE AS(
select ltrim(rtrim(reverse(left(reverse(@instr),CHARINDEX(',',reverse(@instr),1)-1)))) as strg,RIGHT(reverse(@instr),LEN(reverse(@instr))-CHARINDEX(',',reverse(@instr),1)) as rem
union all
select CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',c.rem,1)>0 then ltrim(rtrim(reverse(left(rem,CHARINDEX(',',rem,1)-1))))  else reverse(rem) end,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',c.rem,1)>0  then RIGHT(c.rem,LEN(rem)-CHARINDEX(',',rem,1)) else '' end
from CTE c
where len(rem) > 0 --CHARINDEX(',',c.rem,1)>0

)
select stuff((select ' '+strg from CTE for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```